# How can I get blender to scale based on the barycentric coordinate

Tags: scale

My blender program is scaling towards the mouse cursor, I don't think it used to do that so I was woundering how I would make it scale to the barycentric coordinate like it used to.[image: my3dmodelisWinston]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to help you out in the future, it's called the 3D cursor.  Here's how to fix this, above the timeline to the right of the dropbox where you change between solid shading, wireframe etc. there is another dropbox.  click it and choose, **median point**.

I hope this helps.

Comment: you just helped make teh best blend file

Comment: glad I could help :D